# Turning simple php function into variable

Tags: php

I have a simple function, which I'm trying to turn turn into a query. The idea is to grab the number of facebook likes (which I've done), and pass it into a simple equation (which is ready) to work out the percentage of likes against a target number. I know that the php controling the percentage will return 0.0 at the moment - that's fine for now :) I just can't work out how to get from the function to a variable...

Code as follows:

```
<?php 
function bfan() {
$pageID = 'VisitTywyn';
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageID));
echo $info->likes;
} ?>

<?php bfan(); ?>

<?php
echo number_format(($num_amount/$num_total)*100, 1);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is **return** your result so it can be passed to a variable.

```
<?php 
function bfan() {
$pageID = 'VisitTywyn';
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $pageID));
return $info->likes;
} ?>

<?php $something = bfan(); ?>
```

Comment: haha well you can still accept the answer by clicking the checkmark and soon you will be able to vote up with a little more rep.